# python pass excel file into function via command line

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

The version of Python I'm using is 2.7.

I have this function in a file called RunAPIGeocoder.py

```
APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path=r'{}'.format(input_path))
```

I need to call this process in the command line and I want to simply pass through an excel file

if I change the function to

```
APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path)
```

and run from CMD

> python RunAPIGeocoder.py C:path\Book12019_07_29_16_03_12.875947.xlsx

it will give me this error

```
NameError: name 'excel_path' is not defined
```

excel_path is a parameter in the geocode function

I should note I am not trying to use raw_input from the user because this process will be piped into another process and I do not want user input

part of the geocode function in APIGeocoder.py

```
def geocode(excel_path):
    try:
        print 'Geocoding in Process...Start Time: {}'.format(time.strftime('%c'))

        # Read in data
        df_input = pd.read_excel(excel_path, converters={'NodeId':str})
```

Comment: Is the library the one described at https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/? Because I can't find APIGeocoder.

Comment: no this is a custom script, nothing to do with that geocoder

Comment: Parameter != argument: `APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path=input_path)`. The call to `format` doesn't really accomplish anything. `excel_path` is the name of the parameter; `input_path` is the name of the *argument* assigned to the parameter for that function call.

Comment: @chepner the script works with `APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path=r'{}'.format(input_path))`

Comment: input_path recieves raw_input from the user who enters the excel path

Comment: @ziggy Of course it does; because that call to `format` returns `input_path` unchanged. The problem with switching from `geocode(excel_path=...)` to `geocode(excel_path` in that you are switching from passing `input_path` via a keyword argument to passing the (nonexistent) local variable `excel_path` as a positional argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out

```
def run_geocoder(f):
    APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path=r'{}'.format(f))

run_geocoder(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

Try changing `APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path)` to `APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path=input_path)`.

The first version you provided works because the variable that contains what you are passing from the console is **input_path**.

**excel_path** is the parameter of the **geocode** method. On the other hand, **input_path** is the argument you are passing *to* the method. In your first example, you were using **input_path** as an argument, but preprocessing it first:

```
APIGeocoder.geocode(excel_path=r'{}'.format(input_path))
```

In other words, you are telling the geocode method that its parameter **excel_path** shall contain the value **r'{}'.format(input_path)**, which is some processing that you do to the variable **input_path**. Read about the difference between parameters and arguments!

Comment: says excel_path is not defined

Comment: can you provide me with a minimum not working example here? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Pbn3NtBoomJISG5KzVLJe45OKu790CuI

Comment: I fully understand the difference between a parameter and an argument

Comment: The answer you provided is equivalent to mine, right? Where I use input_path as a variable, you are using f.

Comment: yeah but `*sys.argv[1:]` was what I was missing and did not know how to use it